# How to run gitlab-runner locally

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How to run gitlab-runner locally on macOs?

Hi,
I would like to run gitlab-runner locally. I have gitlab-runner on my mac and I have gitlab-ci.yml. On CI gitlab-runner works as I expect, but it's not working when I call it from terminal.

```
gitlab-runner --debug exec shell lint_project
```

Output from terminal
[image]

one of the question is why "executor not supported"?

Thank you

Comment: I found this link useful, it may help you to explain your question further or maybe help you find a solution https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-set-up-gitlab-runner-for-gitlab-ci-on-macos-8cd80e5bad43

Comment: @witacur Thank you for sharing! I saw this article before. In my issue i'm trying to run gitlab-runner from local terminal without gitlab.com.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `shell` command, try to use `docker`:

```sh
gitlab-runner --debug exec docker lint_project
```

For me it's good.